# How To Run Mysqli query and get results from table where table Like %

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting confused. I have one table called `moviedetails` in which I am added column like `movie name, cast, director` etc.

In `cast` column I am inserted star cast (`fistname lastname, xyz, ghi jkl`) by using coma (,). And while getting results I used implode, explode function which helping me to get results separated by coma, so now I am getting results like,

```
Cast : <a href"/cast.php?name=firstname-lastname">firstname lastname</a>, 
       <a href"/cast.php?name=xyz">xyz</a>, 
       <a href"/cast.php?name=ghi-jkl">ghi jkl</a>
```

So, here my question starts, I want to run a query on moviedetails table with each star name and want to get results like all movies in which having that star present.

On cast.php I used `$cast = $_GET['name'];` so now I am getting that cast name, Now I dont have idea how to use it for showing all movie list in which that particular star is present.

Waiting For HELP :)

Comment: What is present in moviedetails? There is some information missing to fully answer your question. Please add all the information needed to solve this problem. This includes how moviedetails looks, what is in it, how `$_GET["name"]` can look, how your database is structured and so on.

Comment: @JRsz In moviedetails I added movie information like `movie cast, release date, director, producer etc.` And created one page on which displayed results from that table, and In the movie cast results used `implode, explode` function which helped to get result `<a href="/cast.php?name=first-entry" >first entry</a>`. Now want to show results on cast.php page with all movie names in which that star cast is present.

Comment: This seems to be to broad fot Stack Overflow. I recommend you do a littlbe bit of reading, I made pretty good experience with this page: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp If you have working code and a specific description I will gladly help you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to your database:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
```

Then execute your query:

```
// Get the actor name
$actor = $_GET['name'];

// Define te SQL query and execute it
$query = "SELECT moviename FROM moviedetails WHERE cast LIKE '%" . $actor . "%'";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);

// Store the results in array
$movies = array();
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $movies[] = $row;
}
```

Now you can do anything you want with the $movies array.
But like JRsz said everything is in the documentation.

Comment: Thank You So Much ! It's Working Now ! Yep I will go with that link :)